StateFlow value not updating
I want to add authentication by google using firebase to my program and when I click the button , value is changing , but StateFlow .collect{} doesnt update it. I tried to use LiveData instead of that but it doesnt affect , if I will execute authorizationViewModel.signInByGoogle(this@MainActivity) without any statements with button it will work.
(AuthorizationViewModel)
suspend fun setSignedButton(value:Boolean) {
    Log.d("TAG", "setSignedButton called with value: $value")
    _signedButton.value = value
}

suspend fun signInByGoogle(activity: Activity):Boolean {
    googleAuthRepository.initialize(activity)
    var result = googleAuthRepository.signIn(activity)
    if(result){
        isSignedInByGoogle.value = true
        return true;
    }
    else {
        isSignedInByGoogle.value = false
        return false
    }
}




(GoogleAuthScreen)
IconButton(
                onClick = {
                    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                        viewModel.setSignedButton(true)
                    }
                }
            )



(MainActivity)
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


    Log.d("TAG", "Before observe setup")
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        authorizationViewModel.signedButton.collect { isSigned ->
            Log.d("TAG", "observe working $isSigned")
            if (isSigned) {
                lifecycleScope.launch {
                    authorizationViewModel.signInByGoogle(this@MainActivity)
                }
            }

        }
    }


Please [edit] your question to replace the code with a [mre] that we can use to reproduce the issue.
